# Calling units inside a unit

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm trying to call a unit within a unit in pascal. Is this possible?

I have a unit `RailFence` and another unit `fileHandlingRailfence`

Inside fileHandlingRailfence, I want to make the RailFence procedures and functions available without having to copy and paste the whole function over. However, I get an error when adding it to my Uses list.

```
uses
  SysUtils;
  railFence in 'RailFence.pas';
```

The error I'm getting is

```
[DCC Error] FileHandlingRailfence.pas(15): E2029 Declaration expected but identifier 'RailFence' found
[DCC Fatal Error] Proj_RailFence.dpr(7): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'FileHandlingRailfence.pas'
```

Any ideas on whether this is even possible?

Comment: Please pay attention to the description of tags before you use them. Delphi units have nothing to do with "units-of-measurement". Properly tagging your questions helps bring them to the attention of those who can help, and classify them properly when searching this site. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can look at the top of any unit generated by the IDE (like the top of any form unit) and see how the uses clause is done syntactically? `File->New->Form` or `File->New->VCL Forms Application` from the main menu, for example.

Comment: The syntax `unit-identifier in 'unit-file-name'` is quirk and only available to the project files.

Comment: Btw, you cannot *call* a unit but only the methods contained in it. You *include* a unit to make the global definitions (the ones in the interface section) available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for using multiple units is `uses Unit1, Unit2, Unit3;`. You're using a semicolon.

Delphi only allows `in` (`uses Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';`) in project files, IIRC. Assuming both units are added to your project, inside `fileHandlingRailfence.pas`, you can simply use `uses SysUtils, railFence;` without specifying the unit file name.

Answer (score 0):

you need a comma, not semicolon:

```
uses sysutils, railfense;
```